# loading at LMA instead of VMA in code warrior eclipse IDE

Tags: codewarrior

i want to load my .data in flash instead of ram using code warrior eclipse IDE. here is the scenario.

```
.data :
{
    *(.data);
} > ram AT> flash
```

now, all address are correctly generated (LMA and VMA) but code warrior load .data at VMA instead of LMA. how can i change this setting.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.data LOAD(ADDR(flash)) :
{
    *(.data)
} > ram
```